# Problems with access assets

Tags: php, html, http-status-code-403

Last weeks I worked on a project.
Everything worked fine and all assets were loaded.
Yesterday i uploaded my project to the server and almost all assets failed to load. On the picture below you can see a screenshot of my error console.

[image]

Comment: Check if you have read permissions on this those folders/files

Comment: You have permission issue of your asset folder and check jquery is properly loaded or not.

Answer (score 0):

In general ...
The 403 Forbidden error is an HTTP status code which means that accessing the page or resource you were trying to reach is absolutely forbidden for some reason.

`Solution for your problem: Provide 755 permissions to your js, assets, images, font-awesome folders.`

```
755 means :
(7)Permissions for Owner (ex: apache) will be Read, write, execute
(5)Permissions for Group will be read, execute
(5)For rest of the world Everyone: read, execute
```